# Func<string, object> does not accept bool as a return type

Tags: c#, delegates

I am trying to create a dictionary to wrap all sql methods and perform retries regardless to the return type. However, making a Func<string, object> does not allow for bool. Is there perhaps a way to make this work?

```
public T RetryCommand<T>(string cmd)
{
    Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>> mapCmds = new Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>>
    {
        { typeof(DataTable), Query },
        { typeof(object), Scalar },
        { typeof(bool), Execute } /*this is the problem
        error states 'bool DAL.Execute(string)' has the wrong return type*/
    };

    object sendBack = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        sendBack = mapCmds[typeof(T)](cmd);
        //if this succeeds, break

        //if there is an error, try again after a delay
    }

    return (T)sendBack;
}
```

Here is the high level definitions of the methods being called

```
public DataTable Query(string cmd)
{
    //return DataTable from Adap.Fill()
}

public object Scalar(string cmd)
{
    //return object from SQLCommand.ExecuteScalar
}

public bool Execute(string cmd)
{
    //return bool from SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery success
}
```

Comment: How does the top one match either? Your dictionary expects a `Func<string,bool>` and in your sample code `Execute` is the *only* one that does match. More broadly though, I'd take a step back and rethink how you want to manage the retries. You'll have boilerplate code for connections, commands, transactions etc. Want the retries in there? Or a step above? I would say the latter perhaps.

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected the code, you were too quick for me

Comment: What conditions are you trying to retry for? Logic issues with the command, contention issues, or database connectivity issues?

Comment: why don't you use `out` parameter in your method?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I have a bool class property to track success, and a string class property that I store the error message. They get set in each method to indicate if execution was successful. If the bool is false, I check for "retryable" errors, e.g. deadlock, connection or timeout, else, just exit

Comment: Instead of `{ typeof(bool), Execute)  }`, what about `{ typeof(bool), x => Execute(x) }`

Comment: You should investigate a solution such as [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly)

Comment: @MatthewWatson that works brilliantly! Thank you. Sadly I cannot mark this comment as the answer

Comment: No worries, it's too much of a one-liner to really put as an answer.

Comment: @Jamiec I will have a look, thanks

Comment: @MatthewWatson You could explain why that works when OPs attempt didn't? It's not immediately obvious just from seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed a bit your code. But it should fulfit your expectation and it will work.

```
public T RetryCommand<T>(string cmd, Func<string, int, T> callingMethod, int retryCount = 0)
{
    return callingMethod.Invoke(cmd, retryCount);
}

public DataTable Query(string cmd, int retryCount = 3)
{
    try
    {
        return RetryCommand<DataTable>(cmd, Query, retryCount);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Log exception
        
        if(retryCount > 0)
        {
            return RetryCommand<DataTable>(cmd, Query, retryCount - 1);
        }
        throw;
    }
}

public object Scalar(string cmd, int retryCount = 3)
{
    try
    {
        return RetryCommand<object>(cmd, Scalar, retryCount);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log exception

        if (retryCount > 0)
        {
            return RetryCommand<object>(cmd, Scalar, retryCount - 1);
        }
        throw;
    }
}

public bool Execute(string cmd, int retryCount = 3)
{
    try
    {
        return RetryCommand<bool>(cmd, Execute, retryCount);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log exception

        if (retryCount > 0)
        {
            return RetryCommand<bool>(cmd, Execute, retryCount - 1);
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

I recommend you to use [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) so you won't need to duplicate same logic for each method but it will be handled by [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly).